# Getting angle of 2 DoF joint

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to get the angle of at least one axis of a 2 DoF (in SDF type "revolute2") joint? Gazebo 1.2.5. Currently I always get zero for joint->GetAngle(0) and same for joint->GetState().GetAngle(0).

If [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5911df6d46d68133779208e2b70a770fd6c4bc0b/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEHinge2Joint.cc?at=gazebo_1.2#cl-103) is the right method for it in the source code, then it seems that it is not possible, due to a bug or by design.

According to [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/380/fix-hinge2joint-getangleimpl) issue, the current implementation does not support returning angle of axis other than 0, but I can't get angle of axis 0 neither.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/992/getting-angle-of-2-dof-joint/) by [r0nald](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138/r0nald/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is indeed a bug. I've fixed it in this pull request:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/247/fix-return-value-in-odehinge2joint/diff

The change will be released in Gazebo 1.4 (Feb. 1st)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0